# appending a form validation message under an input via a json result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a server side validation which is fine, but I want to display the message under each individual inputs. This is an example of my json return:

```
{  
   "title":"The title field is required",
   "description":"The description field is required",
   "price":"The price field is required",
   "startingprice":"The startingprice field is required",
   "startprice":"The startprice field is required",
   "type":"The type field needs to contain one of these values: auction",
   "condition":"The condition field needs to contain one of these values: new",
   "auctionlength":"The auctionlength field is required",
   "shortdescription":"The shortdescription field is required",
   "offers":"The offers field is required",
   "returns":"The returns field needs to contain one of these values: accept",
   "country":"The country field is required",
   "shippingcost":"The shippingcost field is required"
}
```

This is how I am trying to do it via jquery:

```
$.each(data, function(input, message)
{
    console.log(input);
    $('input[name='+input+']').append(message);
});
```

And a sample of my form:

```
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="text" name="description">
```

I have checked my console log, and am getting no errors, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of `append`.

```
$.each(data, function(name, message) {
    $('input[name='+ name +']').after('<div class="error">' + message + '</div>');
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nbyn37mm/)